# How to calculate distance between two GPS values?

Tags: gps

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I am using the jackal in simulation. I have C++ code which has a subscriber to the "navsat/fix" topic.
My program has the jackal travelling to a distance of 10m in the "x direction" before it stops. I am trying to collect data from different sensors one of them being the gps.
I have latitude, longitude and altitude values. How do I use the values to calculate the distance travelled between two points?

the first value is : lat = 49.9; long = 8.9; alt = 0.0634842;
The value at the end of 10m is: lat = 49.9001; long = 8.9; alt = 0.0634803;

Please help.

Regards,
rsmitha.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/262700/how-to-calculate-distance-between-two-gps-values?/) by [rsmitha](https://answers.ros.org/users/28985/rsmitha/) on ROS Answers with karma: 43 on 2017-05-28

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Have a look at the [robot_localization](http://wiki.ros.org/robot_localization) package, and its documentation [here](http://docs.ros.org/kinetic/api/robot_localization/html/index.html). It sounds like you could be trying to perform the job that it does already. It includes a node called `navsat_transform_node` which performs accurate GPS -> map conversions, to fuse with imu and odometry data to position your robot more accurately.

If you don't want to use the node itself, have a look at the [navsat_conversions.h](https://github.com/cra-ros-pkg/robot_localization/blob/kinetic-devel/include/robot_localization/navsat_conversions.h) file in its include directory. This provides a lat/long -> UTM conversion. UTM is measured in meters, so you can easily find the positions in the UTM grid and use this to get your distance travelled in meters.

---

Originally posted by [ufr3c_tjc](https://answers.ros.org/users/28584/ufr3c_tjc/) with karma: 885 on 2017-05-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [rsmitha](https://answers.ros.org/users/28985/rsmitha/) on 2017-05-28**:
Thanks for the help and the documentation, @ufr3c_tjc. If the navsat_transform_node is already present, when we do "rostopic list" shouldn't the odometry/gps topic be listed?

**Comment by [ufr3c_tjc](https://answers.ros.org/users/28584/ufr3c_tjc/) on 2017-05-28**:
Have you set up `navsat_transform_node` correctly? Please read through the documentation fully. It's not a trivial exercise and may take you a while to make sure the node is working correctly. Once it is all working, yes, it will publish the data on the odometry/gps topic.